# Comparison of mixture distribution models (computed in mixdist; R) using AIC

Tags: r, statistics, frequency-distribution, model-comparison

I am using the [mixdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixdist/mixdist.pdf) package to model length-frequency data into separate cohorts very similar to the method posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/which-r-package-to-use-to-calculate-component-parameters-for-a-mixture-model) (specifically the function mix()).

Currently I have been looking at the size frequency histograms of my original data, deciding a sensible number of components to try out (usually 2 or 3) and then selecting the model which has the lowest chi-squared (as long as the plots/means are sensible). I use the same method to choose which distribution to use.

However, I would like to go a little further into my model selection.

Firstly, I would like to compare the different distributions (i.e. Normal, lognormal and gamma) (components extracted staying the same)- ideally using AIC

Secondly, I would like to assess the distance between the model and the underlying data using AIC

And finally, I would like an estimate of the probability that a model best represents the underlying data, relative to the other models being evaluated.

however, I am not sure how to do this with mix data! any suggestions would be much appreciated (as well as perhaps some alternative ways of assessing how well a mixture model is performing).

Here is an example code....

```
library(mixdist)

#Build data vector "x" 
x1 <- rnorm(1000, mean=7, sd=2.0)  
x2 <- rnorm(500, mean=17, sd=1.5)  
x3 <- rnorm(300, mean=13, sd=1.5)  
x <- c(x1, x2, x3)  

#Plot a histogram   
breaks <- 60  
his <- hist(x, breaks=breaks)  
df <- data.frame(mid=his$mids, cou=his$counts)  
head(df)  

#not sure whether there are 2 or 3 cohorts/components here so would need to             
try both
#2 cohorts
guemea <- c(8, 16)  
guesig <- c(1, 1)  
guedis1 <- "norm"  
guedis2 <- "lnorm"  
guedis3 <- "gamma"  
(fit21 <- mix(as.mixdata(df), mixparam(mu=guemea, sigma=guesig),    dist=guedis1))  
(fit22 <- mix(as.mixdata(df), mixparam(mu=guemea, sigma=guesig), dist=guedis2))  
(fit23 <- mix(as.mixdata(df), mixparam(mu=guemea, sigma=guesig), dist=guedis3)) 

#3 cohorts
guemea <- c(8, 14, 17)  
guesig <- c(1, 1, 1)  
guedis1 <- "norm"  
guedis2 <- "lnorm"  
guedis3 <- "gamma"  
(fit31 <- mix(as.mixdata(df), mixparam(mu=guemea, sigma=guesig), dist=guedis1))  
(fit32 <- mix(as.mixdata(df), mixparam(mu=guemea, sigma=guesig), dist=guedis2))  
(fit33 <- mix(as.mixdata(df), mixparam(mu=guemea, sigma=guesig), dist=guedis3))  

summary(fit21)
summary(fit22)
summary(fit23)
summary(fit31)
summary(fit32)
summary(fit33)
```

Comment: use `mclust` package. I think you can do all what you want directly.

Comment: see this http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/154174_78c021bc71ab42f8add0b2966938a3b8.html it may help you. I do not know which method do you use but EM are common used method for mixture data

Comment: Thank you @Silver_80 for your suggestion/useful link! I am indeed using EM and it looks like mclust does have the potential to calculate BIC. I was hoping that i was missing something in mixdist rather than having to learn a new package/reanalyse my data... so I am still looking for alternative ways for model selection with the mixdist package. But if not, perhaps you could add your comments as an answer and I can accept it. Thanks!